# What's going on with my max value operation in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm doing a very simple max function to find the max between 2 cells, it works on the first few lines, but doesn't work the rest of the way down.
You'll see in the pic the max functions are in column `R` and only find the max between cells in column `P` and `Q`.
What you can't see is Column `P` is  data input manually, while column `Q` references a different cell that contains a formula.

Why is this not working? thanks

[image: pic of max function]

Comment: What is the formula for the reference cell?

Comment: Share a copy of your sheet. The problem may be in the part that we cannot see.

Comment: This is the formula in the reference cell: =if(G4>Q4,G4,Q4)
I had to use the iterative calculation setting for it to work. 
I'll work on making a copy of the sheet...

Comment: Here's the copy of my sheet...https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s0hBSsT8w2p4f-ZXlV2ExLcrnFF2PVj2d-V7K6fuMaY/edit?usp=sharing. Once again, the problematic max function is in column R thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your ranges is that the **values in range `Q1:Q` are NOT numbers**.

Reading the official page about the `MAX` function:

> Each value argument must be a cell, a number, or a range containing numbers. Cells without numbers or ranges are ignored. Entering text values will cause MAX to return the #VALUE! error. To allow text values, use MAXA.

Because they are not numbers they are considered as `0`.
So, when using `=max(P2,Q2)` the result appears realistic.
But not always.

Do test your values using `=ISNUMBER()`
You can correct the formulas by formatting values as numbers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, just formatting the column as a number didn't work, so I used the formula =value(O:O) in column q which looks like it converted them to numbers, and now it works...thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just using a value alone didn't work for me. Wrapping my range in an arrayformula with a nested value formula worked. For example:

```
=max(ArrayFormula((value($R2:$R))))
```

This is probably because my entire column is calculated using formulas. I had to apply the value formula to the entire array.